# Sign document from own site using docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am developing one application and successfully integrated it with **DocuSign**.

I am sending an envelope to the user using docusign API, the email sent from docusign host, when the user clicks the email it navigates to DocuSign website. Is it possible to **edit the email sent link** and **sign from my own website**?

***Note***: Still ok, if this functionality available any other third party instead of DocuSign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please have a look at our embedded signing page:
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/embedding/

More specifically, review createRecipient API: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopeviews/createrecipient/

Let us know if you still run into issues implementing this.